# String interpolation of variable value

Tags: scala, string-interpolation

I want the variable value to be processed by string interpolation.

```
val temp = "1 to 10 by 2"
println(s"$temp")
```

output expected:

```
inexact Range 1 to 10 by 2
```

but getting

```
1 to 10 by 2
```

is there any way to get this way done?

**EDIT**
The normal case for using StringContext is:

```
$> s"${1 to 10 by 2}"
inexact Range 1 to 10 by 2
```

This return the Range from 1 to 10 with the step value of 2.

And String context won't work on variable, so can there be a way I can do like

```
$> val temp = "1 to 10 by 2"
$> s"${$temp}"   //hypothetical
```

such that the interpreter will evaluate this as

```
s"${$temp}"  => s"${1 to 10 by 2}" => Range from 1 to 10 by step of 2 = {1,3,5,7,9}
```

Comment: Is there any logic in there? Do you need to detect if the "range is inexact"? If so, please describe that logic (and supply more examples). If not, `s"inexact Range $temp"`.

Comment: @Thilo: I added the edits, plz have a look.

Comment: So your question is very misleading. You want to compute arbitrary Scala code that comes from a file. That is basically the job for the **REPL**. You need to compile it and then run it. Or maybe not arbitrary code but rather a small grammar of just ranges? Then you need to write a small parser for that grammar. - In any case, this question should be closed since it was not clear and open a new one with all the details of what you really need to do and showing your attempt of solving it.

Answer (score 1):

By setting a string value to *temp* you are doing just that - creating a flat String. If you want this to be actual code, then you need to drop the quotes:

```
val temp = 1 to 10 by 2
```

Then you can print the results:

```
println(s"$temp")
```

This will print the following output string:

```
inexact Range 1 to 10 by 2
```

This is the toString(...) output of a variable *representing* a *Range*. If you want to print the actual results of the *1 to 10 by 2* computation, you need to do something like this:

```
val resultsAsString = temp.mkString(",")
println(resultsAsString)
> 1,3,5,7,9
```

or even this (watch out: here the curly brackets { } are used not for string interpolation but simply as normal string characters):

```
println(s"{$resultsAsString}")
> {1,3,5,7,9}
```

**Edit**
If what you want is to actually interpret/compile Scala code on the fly (not recommended though - for security reasons, among others), then you may be interested in this:
https://ammonite.io/ - Ammonite, Scala scripting

In any case, to interpret your code from a String, you may try using this:
https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/repl/embedding.html

See these lines:

```
val scripter = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("scala")
scripter.eval("""println("hello, world")""")
```

Comment: Michal Januszewski , no, the value for `val temp` will be given from text file. What i want is `val temp = "???"` and it should process it based on whatever value it can be.